# Full Disk Encryption using Ubuntu Core\Snappy

Tags: encryption, ubuntu-core, snap

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask , but anyway :

I'm running ubuntu-core (snappy) on Raspberry Pi 3 and I'm willing 
to perform partition\full disk encryption using cli\code.
is it possible?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

I did ask this question yesterday in the snappy channel of the Ubuntu Rocket chat server and zyga told me this:

> It is not supported, you can experiment and tweak but you get to keep all the pieces if it breaks; unattended encryption requires a few pieces to align and they are not available yet
>
> on hardware like pi3 I think it is not sensible (no TPM)

I then told him about the possibility of using a solution similar to this one:

- https://www.offensive-security.com/kali-linux/raspberry-pi-luks-disk-encryption/

but he told me that:

> then you reboot overnight and it's annoying IMHO that's not the right hardware for the task
>
> snappy will automatically reboot your hardware on update.

So the only option that I can think of is:

1. Use the "regular" Ubuntu Server image.
2. Do a Full Disk Encryption following this methods:
   https://github.com/NicoHood/NicoHood.github.io/wiki/Raspberry-Pi-Encrypt-Root-Partition-Tutorial
3. Install snapd and the snaps you need.